# Correct syntax for setting iptables whitelists

Tags: linux, iptables

I'm a beginner sys admin, and wanted to know something fundamental. I'm experimenting around with CloudFlare set up for my server. There are certain IPs to whitelist, and CloudFlare suggests using the following command on the terminal to do so:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s "$ip" -j ACCEPT
```

Where the [whitelisted IPs](https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/) are to be replaced for $ip. My question is syntactical. Should the command be

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s "103.21.244.0/22" -j ACCEPT
```

Or should it omit the `" "`, i.e.:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 103.21.244.0/22 -j ACCEPT
```

Or does it not matter?

I've done some tinkering around with iptables recently, and was of the impression the `" "` isn't needed, hence the confusion. Sorry for the noob question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are expanding a shell variable like `$ip`, the quotes are highly desirable to avoid errors and shell escape security problems. If it's an explicit string like you've shown, it's optional.

The quotes themselves are not part of the argument sent to iptables; on linux, they are consumed by the shell to avoid splitting arguments on whitespace (this doesn't work in windows where args aren't a vector of strings).

If your ip lists, white- or black-, are very long consider using ipset which is much faster to load, unload, and execute than a long chain of rules.